# Javascript My Array Push is only getting the last value

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs

I have this for loop that I want to increment the year on every cycle, but I'm only getting the last year all repeating multiple times.

```
for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  this.data.year = new Date().getFullYear() + i;
  this.data.noSolar = averageBill * increaseRate;
  this.data.withSolar = (contractAmount * .004) + customerCharge;
  this.data.saving = (contractAmount * .004 + customerCharge) * 12 - (averageBill * 12);
  this.data.check = SREC;
  this.data.total = (contractAmount * .004 + customerCharge) * 12 - (averageBill * 12) + SREC;

  this.dataSource.push(this.data);
}
```

The Year in this case 2020 is showing twice. I want something like 2019 and 2020. Its like the variable is being reference multiple times.

Comment: Well, you are putting the reference to the same object (`this.data`) multiple times on the array. Maybe, you can create a new object inside the loop (not using `this.data` for store the values) and then push this new object inside `this.dataSource`

Comment: You have to clone the object.

Comment: How do you clone an object?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript

Comment: So you would close the Object after the push or before the push?

Comment: clone the object before pushing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A new object should be created on each iteration. You are referring to the same object every time.

You can do like this,

```
for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  this.dataSource.push({
     year : new Date().getFullYear() + i,
     noSolar : averageBill * increaseRate,
     withSolar : (contractAmount * .004) + customerCharge,
     saving : (contractAmount * .004 + customerCharge) * 12 - (averageBill * 12),
     check : SREC,
     total : (contractAmount * .004 + customerCharge) * 12 - (averageBill * 12) + SREC,
  });
}
```

or do like,

```
for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      this.data=new DataSourceObject();
      this.data.year = new Date().getFullYear() + i;
      this.data.noSolar = averageBill * increaseRate;
      this.data.withSolar = (contractAmount * .004) + customerCharge;
      this.data.saving = (contractAmount * .004 + customerCharge) * 12 - (averageBill * 12);
      this.data.check = SREC;
      this.data.total = (contractAmount * .004 + customerCharge) * 12 - (averageBill * 12) + SREC;

      this.dataSource.push(this.data);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Reference of object is pushed in array. Instead clone or create copy and then push

```
    const temp = {};
    for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      this.data.year = new Date().getFullYear() + i;
      this.data.noSolar = averageBill * increaseRate;
      this.data.withSolar = (contractAmount * .004) + customerCharge;
      this.data.saving = (contractAmount * .004 + customerCharge) * 12 - (averageBill * 12);
      this.data.check = SREC;
      this.data.total = (contractAmount * .004 + customerCharge) * 12 - (averageBill * 12) + SREC;
      // this.dataSource.push(...this.data)
      Object.assign(temp, this.data);
      this.dataSource.push(temp);
    };
```

Comment: That code only works if I move the const temp inside the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:-

```
for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  this.data.year = new Date().getFullYear() + i;
  this.data.noSolar = averageBill * increaseRate;
  this.data.withSolar = (contractAmount * .004) + customerCharge;
  this.data.saving = (contractAmount * .004 + customerCharge) * 12 - (averageBill * 12);
  this.data.check = SREC;
  this.data.total = (contractAmount * .004 + customerCharge) * 12 - (averageBill * 12) + SREC;

  this.dataSource.push(Object.assign({}, this.data));
}
```